# SSIS Determine Similar data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

So, At the moment I am experimenting with SSIS.

The problem here is this:

In the first table, I have two users with names Anthony and Tony. In my exercise, I want SSIS to determine that they are the same and to take only the name Anthony.

Can you please help me with this problem? What can I use to make SSIS do this for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Three options for you each increasing in complexity and control

SOUNDEX via Transact-SQL (via SSIS SQL Script Task)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx

Fuzzy lookups in SSIS
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/528243/SSIS-Fuzzy-lookup-for-cleaning-dirty-data
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137786.aspx

Master Data Services 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFcmxVV4Yjo

[image]